# State is not updating in use-effect || data is being fetch but not update state || locally it's fetching data and update without hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

when is console.log() projects result show but when i console log data state that is just showing initialstate(data) with empty array of projects

```
  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    projects: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios('http://localhost:5000/api/projects');
    const projects = await res.data;
    setdata({ projects: projects });
    console.log(data);
  };
  fetchData();
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is not yet initialized, `useEffect` runs after the `render` lifecycle, so such logging is just useless.

In any way, the state should be updated, you just didn't check "if the state is updated" right.

```
const [data, setdata] = useState({
    projects: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios('http://localhost:5000/api/projects');
    const projects = await res.data;
    setdata({ projects: projects });
    //           v Always results { projects: [] }
    console.log(data);
  };
  fetchData();
 }, []);
```

Comment: where is the problem? if `projects` is available it should update the state, try loggin `projects` and not the `data`.

Comment: meant to say how i'll be able to update state any solution ???

Comment: How do you know that the state didn't update? Show a producible example in your question. Checking the logging like you did don't prove that the state didn't update.

Comment: thanks you so much solved. by Reviewing Your first comment

Answer (score 1):

```
axios('http://localhost:5000/api/projects')
.then(res => {
 const projects = res.data
 setdata({ projects: projects })
})
```